# How to check the status of a cash drawer connected to a thermal printer using C#

Tags: c#, .net, point-of-sale, thermal-printer

I need a help. I have developed a point of sale for my client. When a sale is complete a receipt is printed to a thermal printer and a cash drawer connected with the printer is opened.  I wrote code in c# to open the cash drawer. It works fine.

Now my client want to check  the status cash drawer  open or close before a sale. If cash drawer is open sale can not be performed.

How can I check the status of cash drawer which is connected to thermal printer in c#? I will be very helpful to me if you provide any sample code to read the status of a cash drawer.

Bye
With regards
Sadequzzaman Monoj

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# in a Win32 app with the Microsoft Pos for .Net 1.14.1 SDK, you can use the DrawerOpened property of the CashDrawer object, to check whether the drawer is currently opened.
[Drawer Opened in Pos for .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms883867(v%3Dwinembedded.11))

If you instead are using C# in a Universal app, you can use the IsDrawerOpen property of the CashDrawer object.
[IsDrawerOpen using Win10 Universal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.cashdrawer.isdraweropen#Windows_Devices_PointOfService_CashDrawer_IsDrawerOpen)